# How do I clear dynamic memory when an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, exception

```
void a(){
    int *ptr = new int(10);
    throw 1;        // throwing after memory allocation
    delete ptr;
}
int main(){
    try{
        a();
    } catch(...){
        cout << "Exception"<<endl;
    }
 }
```

this program will cause memory leak, is there a way to clear the dynamic memory allocated..?

Comment: This is why RAII is good!

Comment: Why would you downvote this perfectly reasonable, clear and concise question?

Comment: thank you melak47, i know class can be used. i am trying to understand how this memory lead can be handled, if you are working with legacy code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you use the concept called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for that.

In short: Don't needlessly use dynamically allocated memory, so in your case

```
void a(){
    int i;
    throw 1;        // No dynamic allocation, no problem
}
```

without a `new`, and if you can't do that, have some scope based owner handle the lifetime:

```
void a(){
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    throw 1;        // Allocation handled properly, no problem
}
```

This will automatically delete the `int` when it goes out of scope.

Rule of thumb: If your code has a `delete` or `delete[]` or a naked `new` or `new[]`, you probably have a bug.

Comment: *"If your code has adelete or delete[] or a naked new or new[], you probably have a bug."* This should be written at the beginning of any book chapter that introduces dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 5):

Use a smart pointer.

```
void a(){
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    throw 1;
}
```

`ptr` will be deallocated whether or not the exception is thrown. (It may not be deallocated if the exception is thrown *and not caught*, but then the program will crash anyway.)